# How to add markup to the wp-custom-header div

Tags: filters, custom-header, video-header

I have a custom header video on my WordPress site and I have an overlay (an svg I repeat in the background of a div) that I want to live on top of the video.
I accomplished this like so

```
<?php the_custom_header_markup(); ?>
<div class="header__overlay"></div>
```

However this creates a problem. Because the video and the generated pause button are both in the generated wp-custom-header div, I cannot get my overlay between them.
ie For my overlay to be z-indexed over my video, it is also over top of my button.

Is there a way for me to filter the output of The_custom_header_markup to include additional markup.
That functions typical markup is:

```
<div id="wp-custom-header" class="wp-custom-header">
<video id="wp-custom-header-video"></video>
<button type="button" id="wp-custom-header-video-button" class="wp-custom-header-video-button ...">Pause</button>
</div>
```

What I want is

```
<div id="wp-custom-header" class="wp-custom-header">
<video id="wp-custom-header-video"></video>
<div class="header__overlay"></div>
<button type="button" id="wp-custom-header-video-button" class="wp-custom-header-video-button ...">Pause</button>
</div>
```

Thanks In advance!
JoesLost

Comment: An interesting question, but have you considered abandoning adding markup and instead using a CSS pseudo element such as `:after` to implement the overlay? Then you wouldn't need any WP knowledge at all, just CSS knowhow

Comment: elegant proposal

Comment: That is a very cleaver solution, elegant is a good word. A note for any future people reading this. You cannot use pseudo elements on a video element ( that had me banging my head for a second) I just put it on the containing div. Perfect solution!